# Map of 32 Tags of Academia.SE

Tags: discussion, tags, site-promotion

I made a map of Academia.SE, basing on tag co-occurrences.

[image]

Some more description e.g. on [a respective post on meta.math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6479/a-graph-map-of-math-se).

The project is on GitHub: https://github.com/stared/tag-graph-map-of-stackexchange/wiki (feel invited to tweak the plot to your taste).

I hope you like it! :)

Comment: What do the colours mean?

Comment: @gerrit Graph communities (groups of nodes which have a lot of connections between each other).

Comment: My first thought was, "what the what..???" My second thought was, "ooh, pretty colors." My third thought was, odd that 'professors' and 'postdocs' are in the same group as 'career' and 'career-path', but 'masters' isn't.

Comment: @eykanal Well, the graph is about how questions here are tagged (or mistagged). But (as I would (mis)interpret it), it's because master student ask about admissions, and not yet looking at the full carrier path (see, there is a whole group about admissions). Stranger, that 'undegraduate' are not with 'masters'...

Answer (score 9):

I made an interactive version of the above, with always up-to-date data, [**TagOverflow**](http://stared.github.io/tagoverflow/?site=academia&size=32).
You can check tag grouping - i.e. for the sake of eliminating synonyms or poorly-defined tags.

[Code and a more detailed description is on Github](https://github.com/stared/tagoverflow#tagoverflow).

[image]